# Is it possible to interact with ios devices even though app killed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, ios10

Is it possible to create an app where the message is automatically sent from one device to another when both the devices are in the same geo-location in predefined range or in the wireless points like Bluetooth?

I think there must be some way to do this. Please let me know if you have any idea about the same.

Comment: I have the same type of question @Ashwin, do you get the any solution? Please update.

Comment: Okay sure... May I know who are you? I will notify you here

Comment: sureshdit45@gmail.com please notify me here also.

Comment: Sure, but everyone is saying no.

Comment: It must be the way to do this. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In peer-peer connection, It is not possible. When the user terminates the app everything goes with it.

But if you connect it with server, you could try to implement the behavior you are looking for with a `push notification` with content available, which gives you some time awake to download content in the background.

Comment: I need broadcast feature, if multiple devices are in range send file them all, Without user interaction at either side.

Comment: `MultipeerConnectivity` framework will help you! But it will not support when app is `not-running` state
https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity